# How to analyse a factor experiment with feature extraction, clustering and classification algorithms as factors?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, anova, clustering, factor-analysis

Currently I am doing my final project, which consists of designing an experiment to test several combinations of algorithms on a dataset, such as feature extraction, clustering, classifiers and regression techniques. Before writing any code, it is extremely important for me to design all parts of the experiment in order to have everything clear *a priori*; going off course is less likely this way :)

I want to test the following algorithms on my dataset, which is unlabeled:

```
1) Two feature extraction algorithms: PCA and ICA.
2) After having extracted the features, I'd like to group the two new datasets of transformed data into clusters. For this, I will test three clustering algorithms: k-medoids, EM and hierarchical clustering.
3) Then, four or five different classifiers will be trained for each combination of feature extraction and clustering algorithms (furthermore, I want to test on different number of clusters).
```

As you might see, I am designing a factorial experiment to analyse the performance on classification based on different types of feature extraction -> clustering -> classification algorithms.

My goal, then, is to find a good combination of these factors so as to train a classifier to recognize clusters and label future unseen data to one of these clusters.

I got stuck at the process of thinking how to analyse results. I've come to the conclusion -based on what E. Alpaydin states in *Introduction to Machine Learning*- that I should apply a multi-way ANOVA with interaction, but I am not sure whether it is correct to do so.

```
1) Can I perform a three-way ANOVA with interaction to my experiment, being feature extraction, clustering and classification algorithms the three factors of it?
2) If not, what should the best way of analysing the result be?
3) Is there any way of choosing the best classifier based on classification results and how well the clustering algorithm groups the data (for example, taking into account the silhouette coefficient)?
```

I have doubts because I think classification is dependent on clustering: the performance of classification relies on how well the clustering algorithms form groups, doesn't it?

I am learning to conduct this kind of experiments now, and I would like to learn as much as possible so as to extract fair, real conclusions.

Comment: Why are you doing clustering before classification?

Comment: Because I need to label the data in order to train the classifiers. That's something I forgot to mention.

Comment: That seems strange to me. If you use clustering to assign labels and then train classifiers, then you are essentially training classifiers to recognize your clustering result? Why not use cluster indicators straight away?

Comment: Hi Marc. That's it: I need to identify clusters so as to train my classifier to recognize these clusters. This is because, in the future, I will have to label unseen data to one of these clusters. I don't know exactly what _cluster indicators_ mean. Could you explain it to me? Thank you so much :)